# How to get RYB complementary colors in RGB imaging software

Tags: color, color-theory, rgb, color-spaces

I am looking for a way to get RYB complementary colors in software. This means, complementary color pairs I am looking to get would be:

- red - green
- yellow - violet
- blue - orange

However, when inverting an image in RGB mode, you get the calculated RGB opposite, like:

- red - cyan
- yellow - blue
- blue - yellow

For example inverting *blue* (red 0%, green 0%, blue 100%) gives *yellow* (red 100%, green 100%, blue 0%). Doing the same calculation in a RYB color system gives me the values I'd like, for example with blue, that would be: *orange* (red 100%, yellow 100%, blue 0%).

**Is there any way to get complementary colors according to a RYB color system in imaging software?**

(Answers can be software specific, but probably any technique to do so might be transferable, unless it's a plugin or something the like dealing with the calculation.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use kuler, it seems to work on the colorwheel you are looking for (i know, its an extention)

[image: dont mind the german]

Comment: Oh wow, nice tool - can also be used online: https://kuler.adobe.com -> create